# Android app crashes while returning from background to foreground

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

> E/LIGHTS: file:vendor/sprd/open-source/libs/liblights/lights.c, func:write_int, failed to open /sys/class/leds/keyboard-backlight/brightness

And the crash report is...

```
    Crashed: test.qtp.app
0  libc.so                        0x400ffa7c __futex_syscall3
1  libc.so                        0x400ed03c __pthread_cond_timedwait_relative
2  libc.so                        0x400ed09c __pthread_cond_timedwait
3  libdvm.so                      0x40c7f72f (Missing)
4  libdvm.so                      0x40c930b5 (Missing)
5  libdvm.so                      0x40c547a0 (Missing)
6  libdvm.so                      0x40c5b580 dvmMterpStd(Thread*)
7  libdvm.so                      0x40c58c18 dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)
8  libdvm.so                      0x40c8c7f9 dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)
9  libdvm.so                      0x40c9412d (Missing)
10 libdvm.so                      0x40c547a0 (Missing)
11 libdvm.so                      0x40c5b580 dvmMterpStd(Thread*)
12 libdvm.so                      0x40c58c18 dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)
13 libdvm.so                      0x40c8c531 dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)
14 libdvm.so                      0x40c76f57 (Missing)
15 libandroid_runtime.so          0x40207def (Missing)
16 libandroid_runtime.so          0x40208a41 android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)
17 app_process                    0x400c105b (Missing)
18 libc.so                        0x400ec4c3 __libc_init
19 app_process                    0x400c0d7c (Missing)


Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                JobForm.this.startActivityForResult(intent, JobForm.this.REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

---

```
@Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == this.SELECT_FILE)
                    this.onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
                else if (requestCode == this.REQUEST_CAMERA)
                    this.onCaptureImageResult(data);
            }
    }
```

---

```
private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
        new UploadImages().execute(data);
    }
```

Comment: This is not an android crash. Are you using any NDK libraries?

Comment: yes. i'm using ndk library for crashlytics. 

And here the dependency is
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.3@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

Comment: @AbdulGaffar: Bro did you try to debug your code??
If you could post some code & error line number then may be we could help you.

Comment: @SripadRaj If i use ndk library meany what i need to do.

Comment: @Pawan Actually the entire code is clear and perfect. And its outcome were perfect. But once i added crashlytics_ndk library to my project, from then i got the crash issues for every screens.